# How to do assignment in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I tried this way,but seems not working:

```
{if $i == 1}
    $value = $recommend[3];
{/if}
```

Does smarty support assignment operation?

Comment: torn between giving you an answer, telling you not to use smarty, and telling you assignment does not belong in views.

Comment: @Galen: Although the OP's example code appears to overreach, there are many cases where it's appropriate to assign variables in presentation logic.

Answer (score 4):

To assign variables within a template, do:

```
{if $i == 1}
    {assign var='value' value=$recommend[3]}
{/if}
```

Comment: What about `{$value = $recommend[3]}` ?

Comment: @yoyo: You should call the assign function. From the docs: `{assign} is used for assigning template variables during the execution of a template.` http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.custom.functions.php#language.function.assign

Comment: @yoyo what about moving this assignment into business logic part? There is no such restrictions there.

Answer (score 1):

There is `assign()` method for that. Check it out here:

http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.assign.php

Comment: I think he means how to do it in a template, rather than the PHP biz logic.

Answer (score 0):

Another option besides assign() ( which is probably better from separation of code and presentation point of view) is http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.php.php